# Angular service and watching a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular service that gets an `$http` promise from a factory making a REST call, which works fine.:

```
var UserService = function($cookies, DataFactory, jsonHelper, $q) {
    var USER_KEY = 'user';
    var USERNAME_KEY = 'username';

    var svcData = {
        u: null,
        b: null,
    }

    var service = {
        setUser : function(user){
            svcData.u = user;
            $cookies.put(USER_KEY, user.id);
        },
        getUser : function(){
            if(svcData.u === null){
                DataFactory.getPrincipalName().then(function(adata){
                    DataFactory.getBDUser(adata.data.username).then(function(data){
                        var reg = {};
                        jsonHelper.setupRegistry(data.data,
                                                 reg);
                        jsonHelper.resolveReferences(
                            data.data, reg, 5);
            console.log("Request is back");
                        svcData.u = data.data;
                    });
                });
            }
            return svcData.u;
        }
 ... snipped ...
```

In my controller, I do:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.user, function(newUser){
    console.log($scope.user);
    console.log("USER HERE");
    doSomeStuff();
});
$scope.user = UserService.getUser();
```

The problem is that watch gets fired when I first assign `$scope.user` (it is null), then I get the console message "Request is back" but the watch function does not fire again.

Why, and how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Pass string to `$watch()`**

   ```
   $scope.$watch('user', ...
   ```
2. **Break the function** when `newUser` is invalid (null / undefined)

   ```
   if (!newUser){
     return;
   }
   ```
3. **Use promises**

   Convert `getUser()` function to return a `promise`.

   For instance, https://plnkr.co/edit/nzq9O0JMTxn1k7FL9We5

   ```
   app.service('UserService', function($http, $q, $timeout) {

     var cachedUser = null;

     return {
       getUser: getUser
     }

     function getUser() {
       var def = $q.defer();

       if (cachedUser) {
         def.resolve(cachedUser)
       } else {

         // get user from cache. using timeout to simulate http response taking 2.5 seconds

         $timeout(function() {

           cachedUser = {
             name: 'Mr User'
           };

           def.resolve(cachedUser);

         }, 2500);
       }

       return def.promise;
     }
   });
   ```

---

For example:

```
$scope.$watch('user', function(newUser) {

  if (!newUser){
    return;
  }

  doSomeStuff();
});

UserService.getUser()
    .then(function(user){
         $scope.user = user
     });
```

Comment: OK, getUser checks for a user before it does the query, how do I return a promise if I have a "cache" hit and don't have to query for the user?

Comment: see https://plnkr.co/edit/nzq9O0JMTxn1k7FL9We5. added an example of using promises (`$q` module in angular)